# toggle boolean and more

Tags: boolean-algebra

Recently I used this to toggle a Boolean value, b being the current value and self.status being the result

```
self.status = (b-1)*(b-1)
```

This rather than use an if statement

How could I use the same concept to toggle more than 2 values? (ie -1 0 1)

Comment: This seems to be a programming problem, not a mathematics problem.

Comment: It's not clear what "toggling" means for more than two values -- do you want to cycle through them? Using which operations? (Also note that `1-b` would have been simpler for two values.)

Comment: Yes 1-b would have been simpler, cycling would be the correct term, apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cycle through the numbers $0,\dotsc,n-1$ by adding $1$ and taking the remainder modulo $n$:

$$
k\to(k+1)\bmod n\;.
$$

Most programming languages have an operator for taking the remainder; in C-like syntax this would be `k=(k+1)%n`.

If you want to cycle through $a,\dotsc,b$ instead, just shift by $a$ before and after the operation:

$$
k\to((k - a+ 1)\bmod (b-a+1))+a\;.
$$

In your case, with $a=-1$ and $b=1$, this would be

$$
k\to((k +2)\bmod 3)-1\;.
$$

Comment: thanks very helpful - I did try and make the question answered - not sure if I succeeded?

Comment: @peterretief: You're welcome. I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean you tried to keep it from being listed as unanswered: Yes, you succeeded; you accepted my answer and the question is therefore now considered resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For 'toggling' $-1,0,1$ use
 $$x\mapsto -x$$

In general, for $a,a+1,a+2,..,b$, use 
$$x\mapsto (a+b)-x$$

Comment: thanks very helpful - I did try and make the question answered - not sure if I succeeded?